# Foreach data is not working inside variable

Tags: php, html

I tried a foreach inside a variable but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong? I don't see it.

```
<?php
include("auth.php");
include ("database_connection.php");
$id = (ISSET($_GET['invoice'])) ? intval($_GET['invoice']):0;
$invoiceDatas = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM invoices where id ='$id'")->fetchAll();
$invoiceNotes = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM notes where invoice ='$id'")->fetchAll();


$html = "

<div class='row'>
<?php foreach($invoiceDatas as $invoiceData): ?>
    <div><?= $invoiceData['firstname']; ?></div>
    <div><?= $invoiceData['lastname']; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<div class='row'>
<?php foreach($invoiceNotes as $invoiceNote): ?>
    <div><?= $invoiceNote['note']; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

.....not important whats going on after here
```

Comment: Maybe instead of `$html = "` should be `?>`? Something like http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/27a0b2d9b9e6851da91ee48fd2d7f33a15cf01c2

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky Thanks for the reply! But no, the $html needs to stay there as this is used in another function for output.

Comment: Then, as an option, you can put  `foreach` blocks outside the `$html` variable, for ex., http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0bcc7d674d55a7a8240163ff02706e2494830232

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky Hi Ihor, your approach did work for me. Thanks!

Comment: Please share more details. "Doesn't seem to work" is pretty broad. Also, your code is open for SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd format everything in a different way, appending strings to html variable in different steps:

```
$html  = "";
$html .= "<div class='row'>";

foreach($invoiceDatas as $invoiceData){
  $html .= "<div>$invoiceData['firstname']</div>";
  $html .= "<div>$invoiceData['lastname']</div>";
}

$html .= "</div>";

$html .= "<div class='row'>";
foreach($invoiceNotes as $invoiceNote){
   $html .= "<div>$invoiceNote['note']</div>";
}
$html .= "</div>";

echo $html;
```

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot something. This did work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following inside your current php file to capture your dynamically generated content into a variable:

```
ob_start();
include __DIR__ . '/invoice_rows.php';
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

where invoice_rows.php would contain:

```
<div class='row'>
    <?php foreach ($invoiceDatas as $invoiceData) : ?>
        <div><?= $invoiceData['firstname']; ?></div>
        <div><?= $invoiceData['lastname']; ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<div class='row'>
    <?php foreach ($invoiceNotes as $invoiceNote) : ?>
        <div><?= $invoiceNote['note']; ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Remy your answer is useful but not for my approach. Thank you anyway!